Way to specify AndroidManifest.xml file to not reside in main?
In my Android gradle.app file, I have defined two "app" flavors.  These require their own AndroidManifest.xml file.  Both are stored in their respective flavor-specific sub-folders, ie. $TOP_DIR/app/src/flavor1 & $TOP_DIR/app/src/flavor2
However, Android Studio is complaining with this error message:

In plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check' type 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessApplicationManifest' property 'mainManifest' specifies file '/home/crm/src/my-android-apps/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml' which doesn't exist.

How do I tell Android Studio to not look in $TOP_DIR/app/src/main/ for an AndroidManifest.xml file, or is that possible?
Thanks, Charles.

I think I found the answer.  I did the following:

I kept the AndroidManifest.xml in main/, but removed the application-specific tags

I cloned the above and put a copy in each of the app-specific folders

I added the app-specific tags in the cloned AndroidManifests


It seems Android merger tool was able to do the right thing.  Maybe there's a cleaner way to do this though?
